# Select not displaying correct selected value after update

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my select in html:

```
<select id="bgPosition">
    <option value="left top" selected="selected">Left Top</option>
    <option value="center top">Center Top</option>
    ..
</select>
```

On page load I need to update the selected value with another one, so I tried with `.each` `.prop` and this:

```
function setActiveOption(el,val){   
    $(el).find('option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
    $(el).find('option[value="'+val+'"]').attr('selected','selected');
    console.log('selected: '+$('#bgPosition').val())
}
```

All ok for other select boxes, but not for `#bgPosition` I think because values contains spaces.

`selected` attribute is in right place, but is displaying first option as selected

Any idea how can this be fixed?

I also tried with different jQuery libraries

**UPDATE: This is [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b8t1yavu/3/) and how I am running functions.**

Comment: What is the value you're trying to set? Also note that you can simplify all of this to just `$('#bgPosition').val(val);`

Comment: same, in console I get the right value, but on page is displaying first option

Comment: But what is the value?

Comment: the one selected from begining "left top". I also tried with `select.change()` still nothing

Comment: Your code seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/3nexg5p9/. Are you running it in a document.ready event handler?

Comment: updated my question with a fiddle example, look like it's not from white space, in this example another select (2nd) is making problems

Comment: The only select that doesn't work in that fiddle is the middle one, and that's because by default you've got two `option` with `selected`. If you change the logic to use `val()` as a setter, it works, however it makes your function a redundant one-liner. You should also really fix the HTML. I added an answer for you which hopefully solves the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your example fiddle, the only `select` element that doesn't respect the value you set is the middle one, `#bgRepeat`, and that's because by default you've got two `option` set with the `selected` attribute.

To fix the problem, only provide one `option` with the `selected` attribute.

That being said, a better solution would be to just use `.val()` as a setter on the `select` itself, which is a one-liner and therefore renders the `setActiveOption()` function redundant. Try this:

```js
var template = [{
  "mainBgImgPosition": "right bottom",
  "mainBgImgRepeat": "no-repeat",
  "mainBgImgSize": "cover"
}]

jQuery(function($) {
  var Builder = {
    initialized: false,
    initialize: function() {
      if (this.initialized)
        return;

      this.initialized = true;
      $('#bgPosition').val(template[0].mainBgImgPosition);
      $('#bgRepeat').val(template[0].mainBgImgRepeat);
      $('#bgSize').val(template[0].mainBgImgSize);
    }
  }
  Builder.initialize();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="bgPosition" id="bgPosition">
  <option value="left top" selected="selected">Left Top</option>
  <option value="left center">Left Center</option>
  <option value="left bottom">Left Bottom</option>
  <option value="center top">Center Top</option>
  <option value="center center">Center Center</option>
  <option value="center bottom">Center Bottom</option>
  <option value="right top">Right Top</option>
  <option value="right center">Right Center</option>
  <option value="right bottom">Right Bottom</option>
</select>
<select name="bgRepeat" id="bgRepeat">
  <option value="repeat" selected="selected">Repeat All</option>
  <option value="repeat-x">Repeat X</option>
  <option value="repeat-y">Repeat Y</option>
  <option value="no-repeat">No Repeat</option>
</select>
<select name="bgSize" id="bgSize">
  <option value="auto" selected="selected">Auto</option>
  <option value="cover">Cover</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I see, don't know how but still not working in my app :( and I don't have 2 selected options there

Comment: Do the elements exist in the DOM when you run your code, or are they dynamically generated after? Say, by a templating engine.

Comment: The elements exists. Look I am trying with `.text('xxx')` and this is what I see http://take.ms/NemMx

Comment: ok find out that somehow is adding 2 selected, but chrome wasn't displaying. Fixed now. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted

Answer (score 0):

i tried your code in a fiddle and it worked for me.

https://jsfiddle.net/b8t1yavu/

What are you passing into the function setActiveOption for el. It might now be working because of that.  You could call the function in two ways.

```
setActiveOption('#bgPosition','center top')
```

OR

```
setActiveOption(bgPosition,'center top')
```

If you want it call it with the second method, you have to modify your code a bit. here is a fiddle for that https://jsfiddle.net/b8t1yavu/1/

Comment: @Adrian . this updated fiddle seems to be working for me. https://jsfiddle.net/b8t1yavu/5/ .

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you call your function but it seemed to work fine when I run it in JSFiddle. You need to call your function with the id of the element as the first parameter and the **FULL** value of the option as the second parameter as HTML does not concider words as seperate values.

```
setActiveOption('#bgPosition', 'center'); // Does not work
setActiveOption('#bgPosition', 'center top'); // Works fine
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Youmy001/uyun2soo